# What is the standard procedure for getting stuff crafted by other players?

Tags: diablo-iii

Crafting recipes are expensive. You pay like 50 m for Helm of Command or a few m for better Gem recipes. There are some people that sell their services, for example: 300 k + all crafting materials for Helm of Command etc.

I read some of the threads on the official Blizzard forums and some of these people actually stream all their crafting, while others do not. Usually the streaming guys are more expensive.

What is the standard procedure for getting stuff crafted by other players? And how can I get scammed, what should I look for? Like for example I want to get a better Gem or a Helm of Command?

I could get the Gems from the AH, but they are 15% more expensive.

Comment: I don't think there's any standard procedure at all for people crafting things for you; people are charging all over the place for the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things to consider, crafting Gems (jewelcrafting) and equipment (blacksmithing).

**Crafting a Gem** *does not* need live streaming at all. It is simplest to find someone who has the higher level gem you want, and trade them the materials (lower gems & crafting cost) + fee/tip in exchange for the gem you want. You only need to be aware of the standard trading scams and take your time when trading. Don't expect to save 15% of course, usually the savings would be split between you and the crafter.

If the crafter doesn't already have the higher level gem at hand, you want them to stream and follow the guidelines below for crafting items.

**Crafting Blacksmith Recipes**:

> Usually the streaming guys are more expensive.

I have spent a lot of time browsing through the Crafting forum (on bnet) and I assure you this is not the case. Of course, as with everything else there will be a wide variety of 'shops' with different prices; i.e. you can pay 300k for a HoC craft or you could spend 20 mins to search for someone who does it for tips.

- Look for a crafter with ***live streaming*** who offers their services on the battle.net forums.
- Try searching for `<item name> Free` and `<item name> tips`, but don't be tempted by non-streaming crafters just to avoid paying a fee.
- In their crafting thread, look for ***customer vouches***: hopefully multiples, its fairly easy for scammers to get one or two fake vouches from other scammers
- Unless you're in a hurry, I suggest watching the stream for a few mins to ***double check*** that the crafter is legit. Also helps to get an idea of what kind of tip would be fair, but if you're poor then you can just tip like Kormac.
- Prepare the ***exact amount*** of materials (tomes, essence etc.) ready in inventory so you don't waste their time.
- Send a friend message ***clearly stating the item*** to craft and quantity (e.g. *Want to craft 3 Helm of Command please*)
- Side note: for some strange reason, several crafters use Inferno level games to do their crafting, so use whichever character has unlocked the furthest difficulty level (and inform them if its not Inferno)
- Especially for those doing high value items for tips, they tend to be very busy so be prepared to wait a few mins - you'll get an idea of this if you watch the stream beforehand.
- Join the game when invited, be alert for party or whisper messages to confirm item, quantity etc.
- You need to ***give them the materials/fees first*** and then they should trade you the completed items (also make sure to have enough inventory space for the complete batch)
- Once your craft is done, ***thank them*** and leave.
- Assuming everything went well, consider ***adding a vouch*** on their thread - it helps other users know they're legit.
- This is my personal opinion, but I suggest ***removing them from friend list*** if you're not planning to use their services again soon as a courtesy, since crafters often run against the max allowed and have to figure out whom to delete from the list.

Comment: So I give them my materials and the gold first? Then they craft and give me my item back?

Comment: @ayckoster: Yes, you need to give them materials first for item crafting, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I find that trustworthy crafters will do it for free (or tips) and allow live streaming.  With gems scamming is less of an issue as all gems are the same.  The streaming becomes more important when crafting other items as they can secretly replace a bad roll with yours if you get a great roll.

With patience you can try to find a crafter who's got a long history (thread) of previous customers who'll do it for at cost (make sure you tip him well).

Usually I just round up my materials to the nearest whole number and let him keep the leftovers.  Overtime, you'll build up a nice list of trustworthy crafters on your friends list.

Answer (score 1):

As yx says the best indicator of future performance is past actions.

This new wave of crafters has the potential to be every bit as prone to abuse and scams as ground drop trading was in Diablo 2.  As a bottom line, if it's completely unregulated by the game's mechanics or rules you are always open to being taken advantage of.  Wherever possible, use the trade window at a minimum.

I joined a clan some time ago and as part of the trusted group I feel comfortable using their crafters.  You may wish to find a similar group or stick with friends you feel quite good about.